# MongoDB : Get the number of documents in a referenced schema that is itself in an array

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections `categorie` and `deals`

**References**

In the `categorie` collection there is a boolean that indicates if it is a main categorie if it is `true`, and `false` if it is a `subcategorie`. Thus, the `subcategories` of each main `categorie` are located in a table named `subCategories` in the document of the main `categorie` in question. And in the document of each `deals`, there is a `categorie` field that is either a main `categorie` or a `subcategorie`.

**How can I get**

Number of `deals` in each `categorie` ?

**When I search for categories, I need to get the categorie name, populate the array of subCategories and get the number of deals it contains..**

```
[
 {
   name: "catName 1",
   deals: 2
 },
{
   name: "catName 1",
   deals: 0
 }
]
```

**Example Schema:**

```
// categories
    [
     {
       _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfa"
       catName: "catName 1",
       isParent: true,
       subCategories: [,5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfb, 5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd,]
     },
     {
       _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfb"
       catName: "catName 2",
       isParent: false,
     },
     {
       _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
       catName: "catName 3",
       isParent: false,
     },
     {
       _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfe"
       catName: "catName 4",
       isParent: false,
     },
     {
       _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bff"
       catName: "catName 5"
       isParent: true,
       subCategories: [5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfe,]
     }
    ]

// deals

[
 {
   _id: "1f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   productName: "productName 1",
   categorie: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfb" // categorie 2
 },
{
   _id: "2f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   productName: "productName 2",
   categorie: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfe" // categorie 5
 }
]
```

Comment: Like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/CkY-ddAaA0K

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it really helps me a lot

Comment: Your answer is perfect for me.

Comment: @RubénVega Is it possible to add each child category in a table in each parent category?